# Exit F2 focus in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

When pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on a member in code in Eclipse, a pop-up showing the Javadoc is shown with focus on it.What is the keyboard key letting me exit this pop-up?
Actually, pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> button will show the pop-up but without scrolling, is it a bug?
This feature is called `Tooltip Description`.

### Answer

I discovered the answer. In fact <kbd>F2</kbd> in eclipse was not functioning properly because of conflict caused by another app, using also <kbd>F2</kbd> as functionality, running in the background.

Comment: the escape key does not work.

Comment: Can you check the key bindings?  (`Window > Preferences > General > Keys`)

Comment: there is a command `Show Tooltip Description` with `F2` as `Binding`. But there is no command `Exit Tooltip Description`.